# Android Restlet Secure connection

Tags: android, security, connection, restlet

does anyone have any knowledge on how to use secure connection with the Restlet library in an Android app? Is this even implemented in Restlet? Also some usefull links would be appreciated :)

Comment: This should work out of the box, have you tried using and "https://" URIs with ClientResource?

Comment: Hi, ok tnx for the reply. Haven't tried it yet, but I will probably in the near future. Also, is there any way to make an SSL protocol connection with keys, encryption and all that stuff?

Comment: Yes, Restlet has full support for SSL configuration in version 2.1. Contact us in the mailing list for details.